# FFmpeg resample audio while decoding

Tags: c++, audio, video, ffmpeg, mpeg2-ts

I am having a task to build a decoder that generates exactly 1 raw audio frame for 1 raw video frame, from an encoded mpegts network stream, so that users can use the API by calling getFrames() and receive exactly these two frames.

Currently I am reading with av_read_frame in a thread, decode as packets come, audio or video; collect until a video packet is hit. Problem is generally multiple audio packets are received before video is seen.

av_read_frame is blocking, returns when certain amount of audio data is collected (1152 samples for mp2); and decoding that packet gives a raw AVFrame having duration of T (depends on samplerate); whereas the video frame generally has duration bigger than T (depends on fps), so multiple audio frames are received before it.

I was guessing I have to find a way to merge collected audio frames into 1 single frame just when video is hit. Also resampling and setting timestamp to align with video is needed I guess. I don't know if this is even valid though.

What is the smoothest way to sync video and audio in this manner ?

Comment: Resampling changes the samples/second, eg from 44 khz to 32 khz. I would not expect this to be necessary. It's non-trivial, certainly for arbitrary sample rate pairs

Comment: Generally (at least here) mpegts give 1 second of audio ahead of the video stream. And, you would get say 25 FPS of video and 48 audio frames. You would need to sync these.

Comment: my calculations say to receive 1A for 1V, 1152×25=28.8k input samplerate is needed. How to change samplerate online if its not ?